# Laravel Validation between not converting comma separated string to array?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

Just trying to do some tags validation. First checking for number of tags (as comma separated list of id's).

```
class SomePostRequest extends Request
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'tags' => 'between:2,5'
        ];
    }


    public function all()
    {
        $input = parent::all();

        $input['tags'] = explode(',', @$input['tags']);

        return $input;
    }

}
```

It keeps spititing out the message as

```
The tags must be between 2 and 5 characters.
```

Instead of the proper array message:

```
The :attribute must have between :min and :max items.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use custom validation rule for you requirement:

```
$this->app['validator']->extend('tag', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $tags = explode(',', $value);
    if(count($tags) >= 2 || count($tags) <= 5)){
        return false;
    }
});
```

and then rules would be

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        'tags' => ['tag']
    ];
}
```

and message can update by

```
public function messages() {
        return [
            'tags.tag' => 'The :attribute must have between :min and :max items.'];

}
```

I hope, you get basic idea to achieve this requirement, let me know if its helps.

Comment: Ya, that's all fine and good and basically I already have that as a workaround. But I'm specifically looking at the situation in my sample code. For instance if you were to take a custom validator and just `print_r($value)` it would already be exploded from the `all` method. So the point is why is `between` not properly parsing it as an `array`. I'm just not sure if I'm doing something incorrect or if it's a bug in the validator.

Comment: basically, between not compatible with array, that the reason to implement another approach.